# Parse user not saving using phone number verification with Twilio

Tags: parse-platform

I have the following code implemented to create a new PFUser when the user enters his phone number.

```
- (IBAction)confirmButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    // Check to see if a valid phone number is entered
    if ([self.phoneNumberTextField.text hasPrefix:@"+"]){
        self.phoneNumber = self.phoneNumberTextField.text;

        //Create new Parse user
        [self createNewUser];
    }
}

- (void)createNewUser
{
    //Create new Parse user
    PFUser *newUser = [PFUser new];
    newUser.username = self.phoneNumber;
    NSString *alphabet = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:20];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0U; i < 20; i++){
        u_int32_t r = arc4random() % [alphabet length];
        unichar c = [alphabet characterAtIndex:r];
        [s appendFormat:@"%C", c];
    }
    newUser.password = [NSString stringWithString:s];
    newUser.email = [NSString string];
    [newUser setObject:[NSArray array] forKey:@"contactsSnatched"];
    [newUser setObject:[NSArray array] forKey:@"friends"];
    [newUser setObject:self.phoneNumber forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
    [newUser setObject:@"" forKey:@"firstName"];
    [newUser setObject:@"" forKey:@"lastName"];

    //Set profile picture
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"PictureSelect.png"], 0.4);
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"profilePicture.jpg"];
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:fileName data:imageData];
    [newUser setObject:imageFile forKey:@"profilePicture"];

    [newUser saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
        if (!error){
            if (succeeded){
                // Call cloud function to send SMS to the entered phone number
                NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.phoneNumber, @"phoneNumber", nil];
                [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"sendVerificationCode" withParameters:dict block:^(id object, NSError *error){
                    if (!error){
                        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"confirmNumberSegue" sender:self];
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"Error calling cloud function: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                    }
                }];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error signing up new user: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve here is to create a new PFUser before sending SMS confirmation via cloud code. The code executes but the block after saveInBackgroundWithBlock: method is never called and thus the user is not saved.

Comment: already found the error, I used signUpInBackgroundWithBlock method instead of saveInBackgroundWithBlock method.

Comment: flizana, I know it seems silly, but it would be useful to post your solution as an answer and mark it as accepted when you get a chance. It will help anyone else that comes along!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This block of code actually does the job:

```
- (IBAction)confirmButtonTapped:(id)sender
{
    // Check to see if a valid phone number is entered
    if ([self.phoneNumberTextField.text hasPrefix:@"+"]){
        self.phoneNumber = self.phoneNumberTextField.text;

        //Create new Parse user
        [self createNewUser];
    }
}

- (void)createNewUser
{
    //Create new Parse user
    PFUser *newUser = [PFUser new];
    newUser.username = self.phoneNumber;
    NSString *alphabet = @"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    NSMutableString *s = [NSMutableString stringWithCapacity:20];
    for (NSUInteger i = 0U; i < 20; i++){
        u_int32_t r = arc4random() % [alphabet length];
        unichar c = [alphabet characterAtIndex:r];
        [s appendFormat:@"%C", c];
    }
    newUser.password = [NSString stringWithString:s];
    newUser.email = [NSString string];
    [newUser setObject:[NSArray array] forKey:@"contactsSnatched"];
    [newUser setObject:[NSArray array] forKey:@"friends"];
    [newUser setObject:self.phoneNumber forKey:@"phoneNumber"];
    [newUser setObject:@"" forKey:@"firstName"];
    [newUser setObject:@"" forKey:@"lastName"];

    //Set profile picture
    NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"PictureSelect.png"], 0.4);
    NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"profilePicture.jpg"];
    PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:fileName data:imageData];
    [newUser setObject:imageFile forKey:@"profilePicture"];

    [newUser signUpInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error){
        if (!error){
            if (succeeded){
                // Call cloud function to send SMS to the entered phone number
                NSDictionary *dict = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:self.phoneNumber, @"phoneNumber", nil];
                [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"sendVerificationCode" withParameters:dict block:^(id object, NSError *error){
                    if (!error){
                        [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"confirmNumberSegue" sender:self];
                    } else {
                        NSLog(@"Error calling cloud function: %@", error.localizedDescription);
                    }
                }];
            }
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Error signing up new user: %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }
    }];

}
```